# R data.table calculate sum of other rows

Tags: r, data.table

Using R and data.table I've got this data

```
test = data.frame(genotypes =  c('A|A', 'A|G', 'G|G'), high = c(73, 113, 87), low = c(77, 155, 63))
genotypes high low
1       A|A   73  77
2       A|G  113 155
3       G|G   87  63
```

How can I get 3 new matrix of this data, containing 1 row and the sum of other rows by columns?

```
# low           |   high
# -----------------------------
# A|A           |   A|A
# -----------------------------
# A|G + G|G     |   A|G + G|G
```

So I need to get `nrow(test)` adiitional matrix in next view:

```
matrix(c(73, 113+87, 77, 155+63), nrow = 2)
matrix(c(113, 73+87, 155, 77+63), nrow = 2)
matrix(c(87, 73+113, 63, 77+155), nrow = 2)
```

example

```
> matrix(c(73, 113+87, 77, 155+63), nrow = 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   73   77
[2,]  200  218
```

How can do that?

Comment: You mention `data.table` but you are using a `data.frame` and `matrix`. Is this a typo?

Comment: `t()` is a function in R, better call your `data.frame` something else.

Comment: @MauritsEvers matrix it is only for example to easy show here table in 2x2 format

Comment: @autumnrustle But are you after a `data.table`-specific solution? `data.table` is a very specific R package offering functionalities around `data.table` objects.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I use data.table to dcast() and group by specific columns. Result of my manupulations in `test` variable. Now I need 2x2 table to use it in fisher.test()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cols = c('high', 'low')
lapply(
  seq_len(nrow(df)), 
  \(i) matrix(c(unlist(df[i, cols]), colSums(df[-i, cols])), nrow = 2, byrow=TRUE)
)

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   73   77
[2,]  200  218

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  113  155
[2,]  160  140

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   87   63
[2,]  186  232
```

Data

```
df = data.frame(genotypes =  c('A|A', 'A|G', 'G|G'), high = c(73, 113, 87), low = c(77, 155, 63))
```

Comment: Thanks! But [1,] must by [,1] and [2,] -> [,2]

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
setDT(t)
lapply(t$genotypes, function(x){
    as.matrix(t[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(genotypes == x)][, !'genotypes'])
})
# [[1]]
#      high low
# [1,]   73  77
# [2,]  200 218
# 
# [[2]]
#      high low
# [1,]  160 140
# [2,]  113 155
# 
# [[3]]
#      high low
# [1,]  186 232
# [2,]   87  63
```